# component, pages inherited from parent publication cannot be sent for translation to worldserver

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, translation-manager, worldserver

We want to send components, pages for translation to world server, from 060 canada publication. but if components, pages are not localized or locally created then translation option is missing. though translation option is enabled for all parent publications.
[image]

when we started reviewing the settings of all parent publications we have found that we have set different project types [setup at world server] in parent and child which is part of the requirement.

For testing purpose we found that if we use same project type [setup at world server] and client [setup at world server] for all publications then translation option is available for all items inherited from parent.

to summarize our requirement:

1. we want to use 2 project types [setup at world server] depending on target language.
2. if possible we also want to use 2 client [setup at world server].

I have attached existing translation settings on each publication level.
Following is current publication properties in terms of translation tab.

[image]

Comment: The configuration of WorldServer project type and client have to match to create the language "pairs" from Source to Target in Tridion Publications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the translation source and target Publications to properly match, they must have matching configuration (same Project Type and Clients for WorldServer).

See the Translation Manager [resolving logic](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-651F3734-BD8D-402D-A401-F5D0D8BCA17F), and specifically how [push](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-18A6C654-D0EE-433F-8C58-CE6EF860A748) and [pull](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-B757B35C-B142-4B4C-8E5D-37FFCB6B90EF) translations work.

Note that a SDL WorldServer configuration specifies the Client and Project Type that specifies the source language. Also, "If no Parent item is configured, an item cannot be sent for translation."

Be sure you've set up your [Source(s) and Target(s) (and any combination Source-Targets)](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-A6163D2F-362B-404E-8F68-5A8F8D4E708C) as well.